# regex in R to distinguish male/female in strings

Tags: r, regex, string, gsub

I have strings with descriptions of gender that I need to sort out. For instance, if I have the following,

```
string1 = "FEMALE AND FEMALE"
string2 = "FEMALE AND MALE"
```

I need to change `string1` to say "MULTIPLE FEMALES", and `string2` to say "BOTH MALE AND FEMALE".

Using `gsub`, I am having trouble writing a substitution that recognizes `string2` as different from `string1`, because MALE is nested in FEMALE. Using "YEP" as a confirmation string first, I have tried the following with no luck,

```
gsub(".*FEMALE.*MALE.*", "YEP", string1)
gsub(".*FEMALE.*[^M]ALE.*", "YEP", string1)
gsub(".*FEMALE.*[^\b]MALE.*", "YEP", string1)
gsub(".*FEMALE.*(^\bMALE).*", "YEP", string1)
gsub(".*FEMALE.*MALE.*", "YEP", string2)
gsub(".*FEMALE.*[^M]ALE.*", "YEP", string2)
gsub(".*FEMALE.*[^\b]MALE.*", "YEP", string2)
gsub(".*FEMALE.*(^\bMALE).*", "YEP", string2)
```

I need to account for sequence of wildcard because not all strings will show as "FEMALE AND FEMALE" or "FEMALE AND MALE", sometimes they show up as "1 FEMALE 12 MALES" or "B FEMALE WITH 2X W FEMALE", etc.

Any ideas on how to deal with nested strings using regex?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're looking for in terms of the additional strings you added near the bottom of your post, but you can probably use something like `(?:((?!1\D)\d+)(?:\s*[a-z]\b\s*)*\s+)?(\b(?:FE)?MALES?\b)` to get all the data you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured this out right after I posted.

Running `gsub(".*FEMALE.*\\b(M)ALE.*", "YEP", string1)` results in `"FEMALE AND FEMALE"`, whereas `gsub(".*FEMALE.*\\b(M)ALE.*", "YEP", string2)` results in `"YEP"`. So this works.

Comment: There's no need for the parentheses.